# UIView display order issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

**The problem**

When drawing a custom movie player controller on-screen (iOS 4), I use an `AVPlayerLayer` to display. I wish to composite some overlays on top of the player (ad banners, player controls, etc). At the moment, this works absolutely fine with the following hierarchy:

```
UIView(self.view)\
                 | UIView(controlsView)\
                 *                     | UIView [some movie player controls]
                                       | UIView [some more movie player controls]
                                       *
```

The `AVPlayerLayer` is a sublayer of `self.view`. On player load, I add the layer to `self.view` first and call `bringSubviewToFront:` on the `controlsView`, and then detect taps on it and programmatically show/fadeout on a timer/whatever. No issue here.

Now that I have support for dynamically fetching and displaying advertising content, I would like to set up the following hierarchy:

```
UIView(self.view)\
                 | UIImageView (ad banner)
                 | UIImageView (another ad banner)
                 | ...
                 | UIView(controlsView)\
                 *                     | UIView [some movie player controls]
                                       | UIView [some more movie player controls]
                                       *
```

At player load, what I then do is attach to my `AVPlayer` instance some `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:` calls to fade the ad banners in and out at appropriate times. As I do this, I add the `UIImageView`s to `self.view` as subviews with no explicit ordering (hence they should be drawn on top of everything else), and `setHidden:YES` on them.

I've `NSLog`'d and these fade blocks are correctly being executed, setting `view.alpha = 1.0f` and `view.alpha = 0.0f` for show and hide respectively on the ad banners, but nothing is appearing at all, even when explicitly setting the `UIImage` displayed by the view to a known working local image and the frame to `(0, 0, 320, 480)`, plus setting an `autoresizingMask` of

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin  |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

The `UIViewContentMode` is default (should be `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`).

---

**The 'solution' I've gone with for the problem**

This doesn't actually address the issue at all, but I'm now using 0.1% opacity as a replacement for 0% opacity. Effectively hides the element without causing issues, and fadeins/fadeouts are working well.

---

**Troubleshooting**

To make sure I wasn't drawing the movie over the top of all non-controls views, I moved the `AVPlayerLayer` to an additional view, `videoView`:

```
UIView(self.view)\
                 | UIView(videoView)
                 | UIImageView (ad banner)
                 | UIImageView (another ad banner)
                 | ...
                 | UIView(controlsView)\
                 *                     | UIView [some movie player controls]
                                       | UIView [some more movie player controls]
                                       *
```

I explicitly call `sendSubviewToBack:videoView` and `bringSubviewToFront:controlsView`, but still no love. I can see the overlay ads on-screen if I don't call `setHidden:YES` when I first add them to the view hierarchy. The kicker is this: *the ad also disappears at the correct time* (in response to `overlayImage.alpha = 0.0f` in my animation blocks), so I know my animation blocks are fine.

Here is a code snippet to do with adding the ad banners to my movie player's view:

```
for(MyCustomAdBannerClass *overlay in overlays)
{
    UIImageView *overlayImage =
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
     [UIImage initWithData:
      [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[overlay contentURL]]]];
    UIViewAutoresizing autoresizingFlags =
        UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    CGFloat x, y, width, height;
    width = [overlay width];
    height = [overlay height];
    // <snip> set x, y, autoresizing values of the above vars
    [overlayImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [overlayImage setAutoresizingMask:autoresizingFlags];
    [self.view addSubview:overlayImage];
}

for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    if(subview == controlsView)
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:subview];
    else if(subview == videoView)
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:subview];
    else
        [subview setHidden:YES];
}
```

Here is the code I use for adding the overlay appear/disappear callbacks (`overlay` is an object with information about when to show the overlay and how long for, `overlayImage` is the `UIImageView` containing the actual ad banner):

```
[self.player
 addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                  [overlay startTime]]
 queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
 usingBlock:^{
     [UIView
      animateWithDuration:0.7
      animations:^{
          overlayImage.alpha = 1.0f;
          dispatch_time_t popTime =
          dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                        [overlay duration] * NSEC_PER_SEC);
          dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                         ^(void){
                             [UIView
                              animateWithDuration:0.7
                              animations:^{
                                  overlayImage.alpha = 0.0f;
                                  [overlayImage removeFromSuperview];
                              }];
                          }];
                }];
}];
```

As I said, that `overlayImage.alpha = 0.0f;` call is being executed *correctly*.

**NOTE:** Just tried setting `overlay.alpha = 0.5f;` instead of `0.0f` when the views are first added. The overlay FADES IN properly now. So there is something funky going on with making the view 100% invisible which prevents it from being shown again at a later date. No crashes, so it's not just referencing dealloced memory.

---

**Attempted workaround**

I tried sending all the ad overlays behind `videoView` and then when each one was to be shown I called

```
[overlayImage removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:overlayImage aboveView:videoView];
// dispatch hide animation
```

Still doesn't show them, but still fades properly when I omit `setHidden:YES`.

Comment: The hidden and alpha properties are completely separate. If you hide a view, changing the alpha will not show it until you unhide it.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Actually, that's not correct. Even when I change the method to `setAlpha:0.0f` instead of `setHidden:YES` the behaviour is identical (nothing shows), and then when I omit the `setAlpha:0.0f` call, it shows from the start and then disappears at the correct time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I am now using `0.001f` instead of `0.0f` and there are no display issues. I'm still keen to figure out why it does this though.